# I Can Not Update Column In Python Django and Also Its Not Showing Any Error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a `Users` table that have null able column. I did tried lot's of way to update a single column. but its not update the column with any error(Its not showing any error), Debug is On.

The Code below

```
instance = Users.objects.get(username="user1")
instance.left = "A string" #CharField
instance.save()
```

Another Way

```
instance = Users.objects.filter(username="user1").update(left="A string")
```

But all are not updating the column

But In the `shell (python manage.py shell)` all method are working that i describe before.

Comment: Please post your `views.py`, `models.py`

Comment: [views.py](https://i.gyazo.com/4aa9f3671db861df3900764773810284.png)  and [models.py](https://i.gyazo.com/fd6b80645077a107d363d6c74df52b65.png)

Comment: Try like this User.object.filter(username="user1").update(left="test")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did not get proper reason why the line are not executing for saving data in database. But, I just created a method in another page for updating data, and i define the method in here. It's work fine.

```
def UpdateUser(position, position_val, user):
    if position_val == "left":
        placement_new = Users.objects.get(username=user)
        placement_new.left = position
        placement_new.save()
    elif position_val == "right":
        placement_new = Users.objects.get(username=user)
        placement_new.right = position
        placement_new.save()
```